# VBA code to save file only if certain certain checks are passed

Tags: excel, vba

I very new to VBA. I an trying to write a code which will allow used to save a file only of certain cell has the value "PASS". If the cell value is "FAIL" then I want a pop up message stating "This workbook cannot be saved untill the critical checks are passed". The code I've written gives me a runtime error:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("12-Checks to pass").Range("C4:C6").Value = "FAIL" Then
    MsgBox "You can't save this workbook as critcal checks are not passed"
    End If
Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Please let me know what is the right way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: C4:C6 is 3 cells, if those cells are merged use C4.

Comment: You need to move the `Cancel = True` inside the `If Then` block

Comment: If you're checking 3 cells what are the rules there?  If any one cell is FAIL, if all 3 cells are FAIL, or something else?